# Display an image in Applet

Tags: java, applet

```
package org.kodejava.example.applet;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;

public class AppletGetImage extends Applet {
    private Image logo;

    @Override
    public void init() {

        logo = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "/images/logo.png");
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1);
        g.drawImage(logo, 10, 10, this);
    }
}
```

Questions:

1. compalsary package declare in all java program?
2. `private Image logo;` for which purpose this variable can be use in applet class?
3. `public void init()` for which purpose this method can be use in applet class?

Answer (score 2):

> compalsary package declare in all java program?

No. See here for more: [Java Package](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package)

> private Image logo; for which purpose this variable can be use in
>   applet class?

See here: [Declaring Member Variables in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html)

> public void init() for which purpose this method can be use in applet
>   class?

See here: [Life Cycle of an Applet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/lifeCycle.html) and [Applet `init()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#init%28%29)

Comment: @SolomonBindavid: If you think this answer helped you, use the checkmark icon beside the question to accept it.